# SmartGit/Hg 4.6.2 Head does not point to a valid commit

Tags: git, github, github-for-windows

I am using SmartGit/Hg 4.6.2. Setup went properly. I connected my git account. My git account is an organization, because I am working on my project with a friend. When I click any of the options related to git(push, pull, sync...), an error popups:

```
Head does not point to valid commit.
It's not possible to perform the requested operation without valid head.
```

But in repository settings, under default branch, I selected master. Now, I cannot got it to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you will need to commit files. In the Files tab, select file/s you want to commit, then right click them and select 'Commit'.

Answer (score 1):

If you have not get already done so, clone the remote repository through SmartGit (Repository->Clone...).